# For In Loop JSLint Error Message: Cannot read property "line" from undefined

Tags: javascript, for-loop, jslint

I'm running into a JSLint error "Cannot read property "line" from undefined", and cannot understand why that would be happening on this block of code:

```
function someThing(x){
    if(x &&typeof x==="object"){
        for(var i in x){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you paste the structure of the object you're trying to loop through?

Comment: In short, yep, we need more code.  Take [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ZbUQQ8Fk) and dump it into [jslint.com](http://jslint.com).  Other than that late `var i` and empty `for`, both of which the pastebin version fixes, it checks out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few linting errors in the code example given, several whitespace errors, one var declaration error and one prototype chain error. The error you're getting is due to i being declared in the for in loop. Try:

```
function someThing(x) {
     var i;
     if (x && typeof x === "object") {
        for (i in x) {
            if (x.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```